# How would I check which text fields are empty in the whole form?

Tags: php

I am working on a form that will submit itself and show what values had been entered. I have it mostly down, however, I would like to check if a user missed a value, and tell them which value they missed. I cannot quite figure out how I would do this. The code is below. I do understand that this is not secure, I am just writing out an idea at this point, I will modify later to make it more secure.

```
<?php
$name = null;
$email = null;
$username = null;
$pwd = null;
$pwd2 = null;
if (!empty($_POST)){
    ob_end_clean();
    $name = htmlspecialchars($_POST["name"]);
    $email = htmlspecialchars($_POST["email"]);
    $username = htmlspecialchars($_POST["username"]);
    $pwd = htmlspecialchars($_POST["pwd"]);
    $pwd2 = htmlspecialchars($_POST["pwd2"]);
    if ($pwd == $pwd2){
            echo "
            <!DOCTYPE html>
                <html>
                    <head>
                        <title>Week 5 Assignment</title>
                        <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8'/>
                    </head>
                    <body>              
                        <p>Welcome $name ! Please review the following information that you submitted:</p>
                        <p>You entered $email as your email.</p>
                        <p>You entered $username as your username.</p>
                        <p>You entered $pwd as your password.</p>
                    </body>
                </html>";

    }
    else {
        echo "
        <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
                <head>
                    <title>Week 5 Assignment</title>
                    <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8'/>
                </head>
                <body>
                    <form action="; echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); echo" method=\"post\">
                        <p> Name: <input type=\"text\" name=\"name\" value=$name></p>
                        <p>Email: <input type=\"email\" name=\"email\" value=$email></p>
                        <p>Username: <input type=\"text\" name=\"username\" value=$username></p>
                        <p>Password: <input type=\"password\" name=\"pwd\" minlength = 4></p>
                        <p>Retype Password: <input type=\"password\" name=\"pwd2\"></p>
                        <input type=\"submit\">
                </form>
                <p>Passwords did not match</p>
                </body>
            </html>";
    }
}
elseif (empty($_POST)){
        echo "
        <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
                <head>
                    <title>Week 5 Assignment</title>
                    <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8'/>
                </head>
                <body>
                    <form action="; echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); echo" method=\"post\">
                        <p> Name: <input type=\"text\" name=\"name\"></p>
                        <p>Email: <input type=\"email\" name=\"email\"></p>
                        <p>Username: <input type=\"text\" name=\"username\"></p>
                        <p>Password: <input type=\"password\" name=\"pwd\" minlength = 4></p>
                        <p>Retype Password: <input type=\"password\" name=\"pwd2\"></p>
                        <input type=\"submit\">
                </form>
                </body>
            </html>";
    }

?>
```

Comment: I always just use `required` in HTML form elements that need filling out. No need for a whole bunch of complex code and it warns the user before anything can be submitted. And as always, you should do validation on the server-side too.

Comment: That would work, but I would like to check with pop as well for redundancy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
    {
        if(empty($value))
            echo('The ' . $key . ' field is empty');
    }
```

Comment: Would I have to declare keep and value outside of the for each statement?

Comment: You'd have to store the value somewhere if you want to use it.  The way I coded it you are storing it to the output stream because it's echoing it out as soon as the code runs. $key and $value won't match the empty field's values after the loop, but the text has already been written to the user so that might not matter.

Comment: Okay, I modified it so it suited my needs. Thanks!